# Call Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getData() returns null

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute

On a custom template I try to do the following calls:

```
    $a = $this->getProduct()->getData('short_description');
    $b = $this->getProduct()->getData()['short_description'];
    $c = $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('short_description');
    $d = $this->getProduct()getShortDescription();
```

All of them return null, $this->getProduct() being a instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product. It works with other arguments though.

On the database, this argument has properties `is_visible` and `is_visibile_on_front` set to 1.

Additionally I tried setting the following block on the layout without using a custom template.

```
 <block after="-" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.short_description" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Also tried to do a `var_dump($this->getProduct()->getData()))`. 
Short description was in place along other attributes and properties.

How to get the short description?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why titles for Description and Short Description not showing on Product Page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310672/why-titles-for-description-and-short-description-not-showing-on-product-page)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with below method:

```
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
```